# Параллельное чтение файлов и Antimalware service executable

Tags: c#, windows-10

Столкнулся с одной проблемой. Не могу понять поведение Antimalware Service Executable. 
Есть программа которая считывает большое количество файлов:

```
var Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.dat", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

потом обрабатывает их параллельно:

```
var factoryTask= Task.Factory.StartNew(() => factory(Files));
private void factory(IEnumerable<string> Files)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(Files, (file) =>
        {
            try
            {
                DatFactory(file);
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref current);
            }

        });            
    }
```

при этом судя по таск менеджеру сама программа загружает процессор на 2-3% и практически нет обращений к диску. Но Antimalware Service Executable грузит процессор на оставшиеся 97%. 
пробовал играться с количеством потоков, чем меньше потоков( от 2*CPUcore и меньше) то увеличивается время выполнения и уменьшается нагрузка от Antimalware Service Executable. 
Попытка добавить программу в исключения и добавить Visual Studio c директориями в список исключений никак не меняют ситуацию.
Пробовал на нескольких ОС с Windows 10. Ситуация аналогичная. Что так настораживает этот процесс и как этого избежать?

Comment: Мне кажется вряд ли кто-то что-то конкретное сможет сказать, неизвестно, как работает этот сервис, но, возможно, он начинает проверять эти файлы, когда Вы их открываете, а открываете Вы их много и параллельно, как устроен Antimailware внутри -- черт его знает, возможно ему от такого становится плохо, это так, мысли вслух. Касательно исключений: попробуйте добавить в исключения не каталог с Visual Studio, а каталог с файлами, которые читаете.

Comment: Вы оказались чертовски правы!))) Добавление папки с файлами в исключение дало прирост производительности с 177089ms, до 19500ms. И загрузка этого процесса снизилась до 23%